# h:form should do GET request to different URL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF application with URLs like

```
/customers/12345/invoices/
/customers/56789/addresses
```

On top of every page is a number selection form that should result in GET redirects to an url similar to the above just with the number replaced by the one the user chosed. The GET request should *not* include the javax.faces.ViewState. It should behave like inside a regular  tag or as if I wanted to post to a completely different server.

What would be the JSF style to do this?

My form looks similar to this:

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="nr" onchange="submit()" value="#{menuBacking.selectedNumber}">
        <f:selectItems value="${menuBacking.allNumbers}" var="number" itemLabel="${number.label}" itemValue="${number.value}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the point, just use plain HTML `<form>`, or use GET links/buttons instead of POST links/buttons.

The `<p:selectOneMenu>` supports custom content. Just create GET links there.

```
<p:selectOneMenu layout="custom" var="number">
    <f:selectItems value="#{menuBacking.allNumbers}" />
    <p:column>
        <a href="/customers/#{number.value}/#{number.label}">#{number.label}</a>
    </p:column>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Use if necessary CSS to get rid of underline/color and making them inline-block elements so it looks better.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't now about p:column yet!
"layout" does not seem to be a known attribute so I left it out.

I set the default value using selectOneMenu's "value". Apparently it has to be an element of allNumbers and gets formatted using toString() and not the format given in p:column. That's kind of ugly though.

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure what problem you tried to describe there afterwards, but as you explicitly mentioned `toString()`, I believe you just need to explicitly set `var` and `itemValue` of `<f:selectItems>` to the desired type. I just omitted those for brevity (and also because one would usually have a (default) converter registered for it)